# "An html" or "A html"

Tags: word-choice, indefinite-articles, initialisms

> **An** html file with above form structure is given to you.

or

> **A** html file with above form structure is given to you.

Comment: This is a duplicate of a duplicate. It is also [the most frequently asked question on this site](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=frequent), of all times. Please search the site before posting.